# Creating an object using filtered element attributes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created `<div/>` area like this

```
<div class="canvas">
    <div id="1" data-level="0" data-tag="a"></div>
    <div id="2" data-level="0" data-tag="b">
        <div id="3" data-level="1" data-tag="b">
            <div id="4" data-level="2" data-tag="a"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="5" data-level="1" data-tag="a"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="6" data-level="0" data-tag="b"></div>
</div>
```

I want to create an object to pass in an ajax call containing ids, tags and texts on each `<div/>` element with `[level="0"]`.

Something like this

```
var outObj = jQuery('div.canvas > div[level="0"]')
    .objectFromFilter([
        {attr: 'id', prop: 'id'}, 
        {attr: 'data-tag', prop: 'tag'}
    ]);
console.log(outObj);
```

That would result in

```
[
    { id: "1", tag: "a" },
    { id: "2", tag: "b" },
    { id: 6, tag: "b" }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)**

Try like this

```
var outObj = $('div.canvas > div[data-level="0"]').map(function() {
  return {
    id: $(this).attr("id"),
    tag: $(this).data("tag")
  };

});
console.log(outObj);
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/uv5q7536/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works fine. but there is a little problem, the output object itself is a jQuery object, which means it has a lot more stuff than needed and in a for..in loop returns more details which are loosely set enumerable, though it can be avoided copying data into another object using length of array. Also it would be great if it could be added as an extension to $.fn object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will give you the JSON like structure you are looking for...

```
        var arr = [];

        $('.canvas').find('div[data-level="0"]').each(function () {
            var $element = $(this);

            arr.push({
                id: $element.prop('id'),
                tag: $element.data('tag')
            });

        });

        console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anik's and Jah's answers, I was able to combine two and fullfill what I was after, the extension code is as follows

```
jQuery.fn.objectFromFilter = function(f){
    var o = this.get();
    o = jQuery.map(o, function(q) {
        var o = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++){
            var a = q.getAttribute(f[i].a);
            if (typeof a !== typeof undefined && a !== false && a !== null)
                o[f[i].prop] = a;
        }
        return o;
    });
    return o;
};
```

and the usage will be like this

```
var outObj = $('div.canvas > div[data-level="0"]').objectFromFilter([
    {attr: 'id', prop: 'id'}, 
    {attr: 'data-tag', prop: 'tag'}
]);
console.log(outObj);
```

It might not be fast with good performance as I didn't test it.